# Change Order of execution : Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-serialport

Here is the code.

```
commLib.commBegin = function (data) {

    var returnValue

    port.open(error => {
        if (error) {
            returnValue = [data[0], 'error', error]
            console.log('1-1')
        } else {
            returnValue = [data[0], 'completed']
            console.log('1-2')
        }
    })
    console.log('2')
    return returnValue
 }
```

I want to print data,

> 1-1 //or 1-2
> 2

but, If I execute this.

> 2
> 1-1 //or 1-2

I know Javascript is synchronous, but I want to know whether there is no way. And, if there is a way, please teach me.

Comment: Why don't you log inside the callback?

Comment: The open function is likely going to run after commBegin has finished. So don’t modify returnValue like this

Comment: `port.open` is not synchronous, that's why it has a callback function

Comment: @SuperStormer Thank for giving me the reference. I should go and read that.

Comment: @SuperStormer I have more question. If I want to return the returnValue, how should I do? In question, there is no example to return variable.

Comment: Yes, because you can't. You have to either use callbacks, promises, or any of the other various ways to return a value asynchronously.

Comment: @SuperStormer Oh, I see. This is very difficult... Thank you.

Comment: @TeddyBang If you want to return a value have a look at: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)